# How to scroll current view to specific line in FMX Memo in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey

I'd like to scroll the current view to specific line in FMX Memo. I used to use below code in VCL component:

```
TopVisibleRow = SendMessage(LogMemo->Handle, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);
SendMessage(LogMemo->Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0 , TargetLine - TopVisibleRow));
```

Is there any method to jump to specific line in FMX memo for cross-platform application?

I'm using C++ Builder Berlin Update 2.

Comment: Not to a specific line directly, no. But `TMemo` in FireMonkey does have `ScrollTo`, `ScrollBy`, `PosToTextPos` and `PosToTextPos` methods, so you should be able to calculate the necessary offsets.

Comment: "TextPosToPos" or "PosToTextPos" just return integer representing a position of the character but for Scroll, it needs X, Y in float. I need a method to covert them.

Comment: just like in VCL, if you know the position of the first visible line and the desired line, you can calculate the scroll offset. There is no `EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE` in FireMonkey, but `ScrollTo()` uses [`ViewportPosition`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ScrollBox.TCustomPresentedScrollBox.ViewportPosition) to scroll to a specific coordinate. That is most of the work for you, if you can figure out how to convert text positions to/from coordinates. Maybe [`TMemo.GetPointPosition(0,0)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.GetPointPosition) can help.

Comment: In FMX it is problematic that there's a deprecated ScrollTo that just calls ScrollBy(dx,dy) which I guess in turn uses ViewportPosition to scroll. One may expect that ScrollTo would do what ViewportPosition does, but instead it works with delta X/Y and is the old name for ScrollBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works in FMX:

```
Memo1->CaretPosition = TCaretPosition::Create(ROW_NUM, 0);
```